# Problema com pause no keyframe

Tags: html5, css3

Fiz um `keyframe` que esta funcionando perfeitamente porem estou um problema em relação ao pause dele pois assim ele pausa assim que passo o mouse por cima com um efeito `:hover` porem o problema e que ele pausa a animação por completo por exemplo a minha imagem gira some e aparece outra porem se pauso ela para na metade do processo fica uma coisa meio "Bugada" eu gostaria que ele pausa-se exatamente quando minha animação estiver 100% concluída existe uma forma de fazer isso isso pode ser feito com um `:focus` por exemplo se no caso o `:hover` não for possível

segue meu código abaixo:

```css
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans");

/* Positioning */

#slider #slides_image .slide.one {
  left: 400px;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fadeOne 16s infinite;
  -moz-animation: fadeOne 16s infinite;
  animation: fadeOne 16s infinite;
}
#slider #slides_image .slide.two {
  left: 900px;
  top: 500px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-animation: fadeTwo 16s infinite;
  -moz-animation: fadeTwo 16s infinite;
  animation: fadeTwo 16s infinite;
}
#slider #slides_image .slide.three {
  left: 400px;
  top: 1000px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-animation: fadeThree 16s infinite;
  -moz-animation: fadeThree 16s infinite;
  animation: fadeThree 16s infinite;
}
#slider #slides_image .slide.four {
  left: -100px;
  top: 500px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-animation: fadeFour 16s infinite;
  -moz-animation: fadeFour 16s infinite;
  animation: fadeFour 16s infinite;
}
#slider #slides_info .slide_info.one {
  left: 400px;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-animation: fadeThree 16s infinite;
  -moz-animation: fadeThree 16s infinite;
  animation: fadeThree 16s infinite;
}
#slider #slides_info .slide_info.two {
  left: 800px;
  top: 400px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  -webkit-animation: fadeFour 16s infinite;
  -moz-animation: fadeFour 16s infinite;
  animation: fadeFour 16s infinite;
}
#slider #slides_info .slide_info.three {
  left: 400px;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fadeOne 16s infinite;
  -moz-animation: fadeOne 16s infinite;
  animation: fadeOne 16s infinite;
}
#slider #slides_info .slide_info.four {
  left: 0;
  top: 400px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-animation: fadeTwo 16s infinite;
  -moz-animation: fadeTwo 16s infinite;
  animation: fadeTwo 16s infinite;
}
/* Slider Styles */

#slider_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#slider {
  width: 900px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
#slider #slides_image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
  width: 1300px;
  height: 1300px;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 16s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: rotate 16s ease infinite;
  animation: rotate 16s ease infinite;
}
#slider #slides_info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -400px;
  width: 1100px;
  height: 1100px;
  -webkit-animation: rotate 16s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: rotate 16s ease infinite;
  animation: rotate 16s ease infinite;
  z-index: 5;
}
#slider #slides_info .slide_info {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
}
#slider #slides_image .slide {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  background: url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/defaulticon/icons/png/256x256/media-pause.png) 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
/* Text Styles */

#slider #slides_info .slide_info h2 {
  color: #333;
  font-family: "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
#slider #slides_info .slide_info p {
  color: #666;
  font: 13px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #eee;
}
/* Button */

#slider a.button {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0 15px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  font: 13px/40px Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #353637;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 40px;
  outline: none;
}
#btn-produtos {
  border: 2px solid #353637;
  padding: 17px;
  font-size: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
#btn-produtos:hover {
  background-color: #353637;
  color: #fff;
}
#slider a.button:hover {
  background-color: #353637;
  color: #fff;
}
#slider:hover #slides_image,
#slider:hover #slides_info,
#slider:hover #slides_image .slide,
#slider:hover #slides_info .slide_info {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
#slider:hover .slide img {
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  opacity: .5;
}
.equipamentos h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
.equipamentos > p {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 45%;
}
/* Animation Keyframes */

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  20% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  45% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
  70% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
  75% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-270deg);
  }
  95% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-270deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "rotate" {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  45% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg);
  }
  95% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes "rotate" {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  45% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(-270deg);
  }
  95% {
    transform: rotate(-270deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeOne {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  22% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "fadeOne" {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  22% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes "fadeOne" {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  22% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  30% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeTwo {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  45% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  47% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  55% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "fadeTwo" {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  45% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  47% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  55% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes "fadeTwo" {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  45% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  47% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  55% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeThree {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  70% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  72% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "fadeThree" {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  70% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  72% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes "fadeThree" {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  70% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  72% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeFour {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  95% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  97% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes "fadeFour" {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  95% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  97% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes "fadeFour" {
  0% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  95% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  97% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="slider_wrapper">
  <div id="slider">

    <div id="slides_info">
      <div class="slide_info one">
        <h2>Title Three</h2>
        <p>This is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a
          sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.
        </p>
        <p>
          Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.
        </p>
        <a class="button" href="#">Visualizar</a>
        <a class="button" href="#showcase">Solicite um orçamento</a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide_info two">
        <h2>Title Four</h2>
        <p>This is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a
          sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.
        </p>
        <p>
          Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.
        </p>
        <a class="button" href="#">Visualizar</a>
        <a class="button" href="#showcase">Solicite um orçamento</a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide_info three">
        <h2>Title One</h2>
        <p>This is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a
          sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.
        </p>
        <p>
          Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.
        </p>
        <a class="button" href="#">Visualizar</a>
        <a class="button" href="#showcase">Solicite um orçamento</a>
      </div>
      <div class="slide_info four">
        <h2>Title Two</h2>
        <p>This is Photoshop's version of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a
          sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.
        </p>
        <p>
          Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit.
        </p>
        <a class="button" href="#">Visualizar</a>
        <a class="button" href="#showcase">Solicite um orçamento</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="slides_image">
      <div class="slide one">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/4/41tAxTu.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide two">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/1/1hjGftu.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide three">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/4/4OIJyak.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="slide four">
        <img src="http://cssdeck.com/uploads/media/items/6/68BYSto.png" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Você pode pegar o *hover* por Javascript e aguardar pelo evento de `AnimationEnd` (ou `AnimationIteration`) para saber quando a animação acabou. Quando acabar você inclui uma classe que para a animação (ao invés de aplicar no hover pelo css).

Comment: entao amigo eu fiz com html e css puro justamente porque nao sei como fazer isso em javascript e que realmente nao manjo nada disso